# Where is the search media by tag on new Instagram Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

On the current Instagram API we have an [endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) to search recent media by tag, but this platform will be deprecated [beginning in July 2018](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/).

The problem is that [Instagram Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference) doesn't include any endpoint to search media by tag.

Does anyone know how to search media by tag using the new Instagram Graph API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just announced a few days ago, the new Instagram Graph API: Hashtag Search API is now available. Here is a link to the documentation for the full API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/hashtag-search.

The edge you wan to hit is `{hashtag_id}/recent_media` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/recent-media)

There are some limitations to what it used to be, but it is the new replacement.

**Limitations**

- This edge only returns public photos and videos.
- This edge only returns media objects published within 24 hours of query execution.
- This edge returns a maximum of 50 media objects.
- You can query a maximum of 30 unique hashtags within a 7 day period.
- You cannot request the username field on returned media objects.
- Responses will not include any personally identifiable information.

Comment: Can I use `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/` to get username by list data from recent media api?

Answer (score 3):

For limited tag search you can use public web api:

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{tagName}/?__a=1
for example: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/apple/?__a=1

This is just for recent media - I guess, this API does not guarantee all media.

However, this is not official api call. Doesn't need token or auth, so Instagram can change this API without any prior notice.

Comment: It's not a working solution if you need to deal with media IDs as the IDs are different in the Graph API

Comment: Also under item 10 of [Instagram Terms of Use](https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511) - General Conditions: _"We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited to, user profiles and photos."_

Comment: How limited? Is this gonna be blocked the 31st of March? Can't find any docs

Answer (score 3):

As of today, photo tags and @mentions with business accounts are the only way using the new API.

At F8 this year (2018), they mentioned "Hashtag Read" endpoint being available towards the end of this year and it will be largely modeled to the "following of hashtags" as a user can currently do on the platform. 10:50 point in this video here: https://developers.facebook.com/videos/f8-2018/the-instagram-graph-api---whats-in-it-for-you/?hc_location=ufi

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is the answer I received from [Facebook Developer Community](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1679459175430923/):

> Public media hashtag search is currently not supported by the Graph API