# why Instagram not longer accepting public_content API applications

Tags: instagram-api

Today I saw that Instagram is no longer accepting application for public_content scope so we can't use Instagram API which use public_content as its scope.

But I saw that there were few sites who using Instagram API like picbear.com/
.

Can anybody tell me how these sites are using all kind of Instagram APIs

Comment: their oauth app would already be approved for the scope. some old apps have those permission before instagram deprecated public_scope.

the access for apis for old apps would also be removed by year 2020 when instagram API platform itself will be deprecated in favour of FB graph API

Comment: SO, there's no way to make a clone of picbear.com/

Comment: you can use unofficial way of searching media: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831454/where-is-the-search-media-by-tag-on-new-instagram-graph-api/48912735#48912735